# Wordpress language switcher

Tags: plugins, theme-development, multisite, language, customization

Is there an easy way I can switch between languages (perhaps with some flag icons) on a single Wordpress site? Can this be done with 2 content editors on the same page, or will I have to resort to a multi-site set up and point each flag to a different version of the site?

I only require 2 languages, English and Mandarin, I also need to edit it all manually, I'm unable to rely on auto translators

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Paid solution. you pay for the updates and support.

WPML, is very nice and compatible with a lot of plugins. It has a language switcher in a widget and has a shortcode which you can use to place the language switch.

1. Free solution.

Q translate gives you multiple editors

Both are easy to use. Both store translations in a different way to the database.

Comment: WPML is a great plugin, really easy to work with. I have worked with Q Translate as well, overall a nice plugin too. But I've had some problems with Q Translate in the past.
If you can afford to pay $29 or $79 (depending on the license you need) I would really recommend WPML.